# Is it possible to use Kafka Stream Processor API as Spring Beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to mark kafka stream processor classes as spring bean like @Component and inject some managed business logic ?

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype") // is this necessary?
public class TestProcessor implements Processor<Long, String, Long, Integer> {
    @Autowired
    private AnotherSpringComponentBean bean2;

    public TestProcessor(SpringBeanObject bean) {

    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext<Long, Integer> context) {
        Processor.super.init(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void process(Record<Long, String> record) {
        //forward code
        bean2.doLogic();
        bean.doJob();
    }
}
```

In case of a topic with 20 partitions, I configure the num.stream.thread value to 20.
Well, what i dont understand is how stream threads work with those processors managed by mean. Are they creating new processor object instances for their task executor? or every stream thread is constructed using TestTopology class?

Im not sure if I explained my question though

topology

```
@Component
public class TestTopology {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    void start(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder, SpringBeanObject bean) {
        Topology t = streamsBuilder.build();
        t.addSource("inTopic").addProcessor("processor1", () -> new TestProcessor(bean)).addSink("outTopic", "processor1");
    }
}
```